# How to disable an existing Trigger in SAP HANA Database?

Tags: triggers, hana

I want to disable an existing trigger in SAP HANA database. Trigger name is **UPDATE_SERIAL_CHANGELOG**

I tried executing below script however I'm getting error:-

```
ALTER TRIGGER "CM_DB"."TRIGGER UPDATE_SERIAL_CHANGELOG" DISABLE;
```

**Error:-**
Could not execute 'alter trigger "CM_DB"."TRIGGER UPDATE_SERIAL_CHANGELOG" disable'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "trigger": line 1 col 7 (at pos 7)

Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HANA helps in disabling triggers

ALTER TABLE "table name" DISABLE TRIGGER "trigger name";

Comment: As this functionality has been added in recent HANA versions it would be helpful to add for which versions this is available.

Answer (score 1):

SAP HANA does not support **altering** or **disabling** of triggers.

You can `CREATE (OR REPLACE)` or `DROP` them.